# Manipulating class member in generic/non-generic situation

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Say you have a non-generic Foo and generic class Foo. In the non-generic class you have a member variable that is of type non-generic FooBar and likewise you have a member variable in the generic class that is of type FooBar.

```
public class Foo
{
   protected FooBar SomeVar;

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       // Manipulate SomeVar here 
   }
}

public class Foo<T>: Foo where T: SomeObject
{
  protected new FooBar<T> SomeVar;
}
```

Also FooBar is derived from FooBar which isn't shown in the code.

Say there is a method in the non-generic class which does some data manipulation with the member variable SomeVar.  Now the issue is that if the generic class Foo is instantiated, the method that is implemented in the non-generic class only has reference to the non-generic SomeVar and doesn't have any knowledge about the generic variable.

Now it seems the only way around this is to override the DoSomething method in the generic class which would allow it to know about the generic variable.

I guess the issue with this approach is that the logic is kind of duplicated from the non-generic to generic class. Is there any alternatives to this issue?

Updated:
I have updated the classes to be more inline with my problem:

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
   // Abstract class that handles how the object is loaded when querying database for an object
}

public class Name : BaseObject
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;} 
   public string LastName {get;set;} 
   public Date DOB {get;set;}
}

public interface IData
{
   List<string> SearchFields;
   string timestamp;
   Search search; // Search is a class that will query the database for a given object and because this is a non generic version, it'll bring back a list of base object
}

public interface IData<T> : IData, where T: BaseObject
{
   Search<T> search; // Bring back a list of <T>
}

public class BrowseData: IData
{
   Search search;
} 

public class BrowseData<T>: BrowseData, IData<T> where T: BaseObject
{
   Search<T> search;
}

public class BrowseBuilder
{
   protected BrowseData Data;
   public BrowseBuilder(BrowseData data)
   {
      Data = data;
   }

   public void DoRender()
   {
       // Using the data provided does the rendering
   }
}

public class BrowseBuilder<T>: BrowseBuilder where T: BaseObject
{
   protected new BrowseData<T> Data;
   public BrowseBuilder(BrowseData<T> data)
   {
      Data = data;
   }
}
```

My issue is that method DoRender implemented in nongeneric class BrowseBuilder, which is using the nongeneric data/search to do the rendering which would return a list of baseObject whereas the generic version would return a list of T.

Maybe I'm looking at this wrong and the search should be non-generic regardless and the base method that manipulate it should just return the list of baseObject instead.

Comment: Maybe more help can be given we gave `Foo` and `FooBar` some names that are more in line with what you're trying to solve and a bit of explanation of what you're trying to achieve - and then we can look at alternatives.

Comment: This isn't going to work anyway because `FooBar<T> SomeVar` *hides* `FooBar SomeVar`; it doesn't override it. It's a totally distinct thing, that nothing in `Foo` (including `DoSomething`) will ever have any knowledge of/impact on. You need to go a step backwards and post the problem you're trying to solve, because this solution is wrong.

Comment: I vote for more information as people are answering and by doing so trying to solve the problem the OP presented rather than the real-world problem that the OP is trying to solve. If it feels wrong, it probably is wrong!

Comment: @AntP Yes I'm aware that new is going to hide the base SomeVar as you can't manipulate return types through inheritance. The problem is more or less refactoring existing class that are non-generic and make them generic. FooBar<T> is derived from FooBar, which isn't shown in the code as stated below.

Comment: Updated with more information.  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using an interface:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    // methods used for modifications
}

public class FooBar : IFooBar 
{
    // implement modification methods
}

public class FooBar<T> : IFooBar where T : SomeClass
{
    // implement modification methods
}

public class Foo
{
   protected IFooBar SomeVar;

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       // Manipulate SomeVar via IFooBar interface here 
   }
}

public class Foo<T>: Foo where T: SomeObject
{

}
```

This may look like I am just moving the problem around but you would need to implement different modification code for `FooBar` and `FooBar<T>` anyway if they do not have a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but it does the job: you can define an event in the base-class to expose a change of value in `SomeVar`, and update the property in the derived class accordingly. And vice versa. Implicitly this means that `FooBar<T>` is derived from `FooBar`, which isn't shown in your code.

```
public class Foo {
    private FooBar _someVar;
    protected FooBar SomeVar {
        get { return _someVar; }
        set {
            if (_someVar != value) {
                _someVar = value; 
                OnSomeVarUpdated();
            }
        }
    }

    protected event EventHandler SomeVarUpdated;
    private void OnSomeVarUpdated() {
        var someVarUpdated = SomeVarUpdate;
        if (someVarUpdated != null) {
            someVarUpdated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething() {
        // Manipulate SomeVar here
        var someVar = ....;
        SomeVar = someVar;
    }
}

public class Foo<T>: Foo where T: SomeObject {
    public Foo() {
        OnSomeVarUpdated += () => {
            // Pull new value from base
            SomeVar = (FooBar<T>)base.SomeVar;
        };
    }

    private FooBar<T> _someVar;
    protected new FooBar<T> SomeVar {
        get { return _someVar; }
        set {
            if (_someVar != value) {
                _someVar = value;
                // Push new value to base
                base.SomeVar = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would choose different approaches based on the context, situation and what you need it for. For described problem there is no universal solution. Providing more context details would be helpful to provide more precise answer.

You asked for alternatives, here they are:

- Move the logic to the `FooBar` class. Directly or via interface it depends. Then your `Foo` will have `DoSomething()` proxy which would invoke the actual method directly on actual `FooBar` instances.
- If `FooBar` is simple get/set class without logic solution above would break this pattern. To overcome this create another class meant for `FooBar` manipulation which would implement the required methods.
- Reverse the inheritance. Instead of `Foo<T> : Foo` make it `Foo : Foo<SomeClass>`. But beware - things might get messy when classes are ment for further inheritance. Also this solution is not applicable in every case. This very slightly touches the  [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) topic.

**Footnote**

Also I would recommend **not** to shadow `protected FooBar SomeVar` in your `Foo<T>` with another member unless it is performance critical. Instead use properties and property in `Foo<T>` will return only casted value from base class. Having it this way you will end up with only one member in base class. It will be impossible to have different values in `FooBar.SomeVar` and `FooBar<T>.SomeVar`.